# How to properly use Task.ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I encountered a simple problem when trying to test TPL. I would like to get numbers (from 1 to 1000) for example in the console window.

This is the code that I have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(Calculate).ContinueWith(task =>
                                                          {
                                                              Task.WaitAll();
                                                              Console.ReadKey();
                                                          });

    }

    private static void Calculate()
    {
        for (var number = 0; number < 1000; number++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that window just closes and it doesn't show anything. I know that I messed something up in ContinueWith method. I suspect that ContinueWith is not executed (because window just closes without my input) but I don't know why.

Any suggestions are helpful (Tried reading MSDN but to no avail). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't the `StartNew` create a new thread? because your main thread will just continue and will exit the application. shouldn't something be coded to at least hold the main thread until your background stuff is done?

Comment: I always thought that StartNew starts a task. Quote from MSDN: "Creates and starts a task." Link itself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx

Comment: well it's part of TPL (task parallel library) so I'd guess it still relies on threads under water. Did you try to add a Console.ReadLine before your main method exits? Never tried anything with TPL but my best guess is that your application just exits and the rest of your implementation is fine

Comment: the doctor makes sense :). tried it here in a unit test. his solution works

Comment: @bas is correct; the task is started asynchronously on a new thread, and the existence of that thread does not prevent control from falling off the end of Main and terminating the process.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Continuation runs asynchronously. If you do a little test:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Calculate).ContinueWith(task =>
                                                      {
                                                          Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
                                                      });
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You'll see

> Press ENTER to close...
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> ...
>
> 999
>
> Finished!

Because the continuation doesn't block.

If you want to block the main execution thread to wait for the task, you can do:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Calculate);
task.Wait();
```

And it will block on `Wait`.

Comment: djeeze they really made life easy with TPL... I should dive into this stuff too :). +1, quick and swift answer!

Comment: @bas Yes they did :) I really, really like the TPL, especially when paired with `async` & `await` in .NET 4.5. And then there's also TPL Dataflow...

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand the basic idea behind this. :)

Comment: Do I need to pay attention to anything additional when an error might occur?